# GCP service roles?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

As I have purchased GCP service from a third party, they have provided me owner rights for the same service. We want admin rights for the same which only the party has already. I just want to know that is there any restriction in giving such rights.

Comment: The term `ADMIN` is only used with specific services. The most powerful Google Cloud Project role is `PROJECT OWNER` aka `OWNER`. Double check to see if there are any other IAM members with `OWNER`, `EDITOR` or `VIEWER`. Those are the legacy permissions that are very powerful. Only team members you control should have `OWNER` and not the third party vendor. Google has some good videos on Identity and Access Management (IAM) on YouTube.

Comment: Also make sure your project is not part of their `ORGANIZATION` which means they own  your project and can grant `OWNER` through inheritance. The same videos and/or Google's documentation will help you understand.

Comment: No matter where you purchase your Google Cloud service, nobody should have any rights to your project. If they do have or insist on it, immediately close the account and go direct with Google Cloud. There is absolutely no reason for any third party to have rights to a project that you own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most privileged role is the owner one; [John Hanley's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) words:

> The term ADMIN is only used with specific services. The most powerful Google Cloud Project role is PROJECT OWNER aka OWNER. Double check to see if there are any other IAM members with OWNER, EDITOR or VIEWER. Those are the legacy permissions that are very powerful. Only team members you control should have OWNER and not the third party vendor. Google has some good videos on Identity and Access Management (IAM) on YouTube.

And this is what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions) says:

> Granting the owner role at the organization level doesn't allow you to update the organization's metadata. However, it allows you to modify projects and other resources under that organization.

It's as [John Handley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) pointed out - if there is anyone else beside you (not a member of your team, etc) that has `owner` role then go directly to Google.

What is also very important that John pointed out:

> Also make sure your project is not part of their ORGANIZATION which means they own your project and can grant OWNER through inheritance.

If this is not the case just make sure your project(s) is(are) in the [separate organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-multiple-orgs#effects_of_using_multiple_organization_nodes).

You may also find usefull a documentation about [managing organizations in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations).